# Converting mm/yyyy string to date pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to convert a string column that has no date just mm/yyyy to a date column with format mm/1/yyyy.

The current code I have is

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
monthdf.select(col("PP Month"),to_date(col("PP Month"),"m/yyyy").alias("date")).show()
```

but this returns null. Example of how the string column is formatted is 6/2021.

Comment: `m` is minute in Spark.  `M` is for Month.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = (
    df.withColumn('date', f.date_format(f.to_date(f.concat(f.lit('1/'), f.col('PP Month')), 'd/M/yyyy'), 'MM/d/yyyy'))
)
```

Comment: You can also use regexp_replace.